# ngTable how can I filter data programmatically from AngularJS code?

Tags: angularjs, filter, ngtable

I have a table, that is generated by ng-Table.
Where I have:

```
<td data-title="'Identity ID'" filter="{ identityId: 'text' }">application.identityId</td>
```

So I can filter data using filter on table.

But how can I trigger same filter from code some kind of like? :

```
   $scope.applicationsTable.filter("{ identityId: 'test123' }");
```

Comment: In your controller inject $filter service and use it like this $filter('filter')($scope.applicationsTable, {identityId:'test123'},true) which true is for exact match

Comment: May be I should pass an array of data instead? $scope.applicationsTable.data ? Because I get Error: [filter:notarray]

Comment: But even if I do so I get nothing changing in table? Maybe I should trigger some refresh event after this?

Comment: Yep, in your case! It depends on filter type. The one I show is for array! But you can use other like $filter('date') or $filter('currency') and more!

Comment: Can you describe what change you wanted? Like sorting or something?

Comment: I want to filter table rows by identityId that for example equals to 'text123'.

Comment: I want to see only rows that match identityId equals to 'text123'. But this command has to run from code, but not using generic ng-Table Filter field.

Answer (score 0):

To ilastrate what I mean here is an [example of plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TCPDKg86gI4xhklPOCRT?p=preview)

FIY, I used $timeout for 5second in the example,

```
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.datas = $filter('filter')($scope.datas,{id:'24503'},true);
  },5000)
```